# View data to another page in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem for display data from page to another page.
This is index.php:

```
<?php
    include '../php/connect.php';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user
                          ORDER BY user.id_user DESC") or die(mysql_error());


    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){    

      echo '<tr><td colspan="6">Tidak ada data!</td></tr>';

    }else{  

      while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 

        echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'.$data['id_user'].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$data['name'].'</td>';    
          echo '<td>'.$data['email'].'</td>';
          echo '<td><a href="../bukti_bayar/' .$data['upload'].'" target="_blank">View File</a></td>';
          echo '<td><a href="confirm_pembayaran.php/'.$data['id_user'].'">Konfirmasi</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        ?>
        <?php
 }}
 ?>
```

This is confirm_pembayaran.php

```
    <?php
    include '../php/connect.php';

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user
                          WHERE id_user=$id_user") or die(mysql_error());


    if(mysql_fetch_array($query) == 0){ 

      echo '<tr><td colspan="6">Tidak ada data!</td></tr>';

    }else{  

      while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 

        echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'.$data['id_user'].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$data['name'].'</td>';    
          echo '<td>'.$data['email'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        ?>
        <?php
 }}
 ?>
```

The problem is in confirm_pembayaran.php for id_user that i was click from index.php not display in confirm_pembayaran.php. What should i do for confirm_pembayaran.php?

Comment: both are same files ?

Comment: both two page. Data from page one will show to the next page too @TilakMadichetti

Answer (score 0):

On the index page change the link to something like this ( unless you have set your .htaccess file up to accept links as they were generated )

You should, however, not be using the `mysql_` family of functions as they have been deprecated. The code, as it is now is vulnerable to sql injection - I merely posted this to show how to pass the user_id parameter from one page to another which was what ( I think ) you wanted

```
/* index.php */
<a href="confirm_pembayaran.php?user_id='.$data['id_user'].'">Konfirmasi</a>


/* confirm_pembayaran.php */
$user_id=isset( $_GET['user_id'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_GET,'user_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : false;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user
                          WHERE id_user='{$user_id}'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: still can't display data @ramraider

Comment: does the url look correct? ie: `confirm_pembayaran.php?user_id=23` etc
on the `confirm_pembayaran.php` page print the final SQL before executing and confirm that it looks correct ~ try running the resultant sql in your mysql client / gui

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass your user id in query string correctly like below:

**index.php**

Changes this line

```
echo '<td><a href="confirm_pembayaran.php/'.$data['id_user'].'">Konfirmasi</a></td>';
```

To

```
echo '<td><a href="confirm_pembayaran.php?id_user='.$data['id_user'].'">Konfirmasi</a></td>';
```

Then you need to change **confirm_pembayaran.php**

```
<?php
    include '../php/connect.php';
    $id_user = $_GET['id_user']; // Add this line for get your user id

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user
                          WHERE id_user=$id_user") or die(mysql_error());


    if(mysql_fetch_array($query) == 0){ 

      echo '<tr><td colspan="6">Tidak ada data!</td></tr>';

    }else{  

      while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 

        echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'.$data['id_user'].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$data['name'].'</td>';    
          echo '<td>'.$data['email'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        ?>
        <?php
 }}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is:
In index.php

```
<a href="confirm_pembayaran.php?userId='.$data['id_user'].'">Konfirmasi</a>
```

in confirm_pembayaran.php

```
$id_user = intval($_GET['userId']);
```

Comment: still can't display data @quentino

Comment: @DavidWinalda how looks like url on confirm_pembayaran.php site?